# Image validation not working If using ajaxForm

Tags: validation, file-upload, laravel-4, ajaxform

I tried googling and saw other questions posted at this forum but could not find any solution for my issue. I am using Jquery **ajaxForm** method to submit form. My form contains one **file** field too in the form that can be used to upload a picture. I have defined the validation in my model. But the issue is even i am uploading a correct `jpg` file, still i am getting error message that

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Validation\\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given.
```

### Javascript Code

```
$('#create_form').ajaxForm({
    dataType:'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);    
    } 
}).submit();
```

### Controllder Code

```
if ($file = Input::file('picture')) {
    $validator = Validator::make($file, User::$file_rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        foreach ($messages->all(':message') as $message) {
            echo $message; exit;
        }
        return Response::json(array('message'=>$response, 'status'=>'failure'));
    } else {
        // do rest 
    }
}
```

### Model Code

```
public static $file_rules = array(
    'picture' => 'required|max:2048|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
);
```

### POST Request

[image]

I know that my validation defined in the model expects an array. But by passing `$file` in the validator, an object is passed. Then i changed the code like:

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('picture' => $file->getClientOriginalName()), User::$file_rules);
```

Now i am getting error:

```
The picture must be a file of type: jpg, JPEG, png,gif.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you pass file object directly to validate. [Validator::make()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php#L87) method takes all four parameters as array. Moreover, you need to pass the whole file object as value so that `Validator` can validate mime type, size, etc. That's why your code should be like that.

```
$input = array('picture' => Input::file('picture'));
$validator = Validator::make($input, User::$file_rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    foreach ($messages->all(':message') as $message) {
        echo $message; exit;
    }
    return Response::json(array('message'=>$response, 'status'=>'failure'));
} else {
    // do rest 
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: After replacing your code, i am getting correct error for file extension but when i upload a bulky file having size greater than allowed size of 200kb then i get the error "The picture field is required." I could not understand why this error is coming.

Comment: I have no problem when I am testing with postman. Let me know detail to solve it.

Comment: I have updated my code of model in my question. So when i try to upload an image having size greater than 2MB then i get the error message "The picture field is required". Can increasing size of max_upload_size may help?

Comment: Yes . This happen because of this issue. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2433 Please increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try rule like this.

```
$rules = array(
 'picture' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
);
```

or try removing 'mimes'